# Complex subsorts on dictionary of arrays with Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, unicode

I'm trying to manage citations and references for my thesis. I've written a program that automatically produces a reference list, but I'm trying to find a clever way of sorting it.

The dictionary produces looks like:

```
ref_list={
'ref_id_1': ['2009',  'AAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME;ZAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_2': ['2014',  'BAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_3': ['2012a', 'FAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_4': ['2012c', 'ĞAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME;YAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_5': ['2012b', 'ØAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_6': ['1993',  'CAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME;XAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME;WAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_7': ['1983',  'ÂAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME'],
'ref_id_8': ['2005',  'GAUTHOR, FIRSTNAME']
}
```

And needs to be sorted first by Author, then by Year. At the minute I'm using...

```
a=sorted(list(ref_list.items()), key=lambda x: x[1][0])
sorted_ref_list=sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1][1])
```

Which is fine, but the Unicode characters end up at the end of the list, instead of Â coming after A and Ğ coming after G.

Any suggestions on how to introduce locale sorting into this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called [*collation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation): there is a standard way to transform unicode strings into normalized strings which can be used as sorting keys. In Python this can be achieved using the [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/locale.html) module:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
a=sorted(list(ref_list.items()), key=lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x[1][0]))
sorted_ref_list=sorted(a, key=lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x[1][1]))
```

where the `locale.strxfrm` function will collate the string according to the locale set by `locale.setlocale`.

Comment: You superhero. Works perfectly. Thank you!